# sklearn. ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, python-3.8

On this line

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I get error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The
>   specified module could not be found.

How to fix it?

Python 3.8 (32 bit) on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Which version of sklearn you are using?

Comment: This packaging issue is being tracked at: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15899

In the mean time you can install scikt-learn from conda-forge:

`conda install conda-forge::scikit-learn`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem and downgrading to version less than 0.22 solved the same
Please downgrade the version of sklearn to 0.21 or less

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Use, **pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3** to install 0.21 version

Comment: I tried pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3  but now it's giving an error saying No module named 'Cython'

Answer (score -1):

Installing the previous version of `sklearn` solved this for me.

Do it with:
`pip install -U scikit-learn==0.21rc2`

Just to let you know, if you want to use it with Python 3.5 or never:

> Warning
>
> Scikit-learn 0.20 was the last version to support Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. Scikit-learn now requires Python 3.5 or newer.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html